# Why do temporary/files directories get deleted before returning from 'with' block and not after?

Tags: python, fastapi, openpyxl, temporary-files

I'm trying to return an excel file (type is probably not relevant) that is modified from a template using `openpyxl` and `FastAPI`, but I get a `File at path C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpg3am6f8d\\1050669-export.xlsx does not exist.`

If I go to the temp folder I can see the temp directory appear (and the file is there), but they get deleted before the return statement is executed. If I `print(os.path.exists(path))` before the return statement, I get `True`.

```
with TemporaryDirectory() as tmp:
    path = os.path.join(tmp, id + "-export.xlsx")
    wb.save(path)

    return FileResponse(path)
```

Is there a way to prevent the directory/file begin deleted before the return statement? Or is there some other way I should be doing this?

Comment: It seems that the file is not as temporary as you want it to be. I don't think *before* and *after* would make a difference

Comment: Hello, I am not verified this but, seems to me that the life cycle for the temporal directory will be on the context only, so, before the context ends(with statement), the temporal directory will be removed.

Comment: `FileResponse` is probably an object that **later** reads the file (In the context of your framework, FastAPI?) So the object is created but hasn't read the file yet when you return it. You probably just want to write the file directly to the response instead of using `FileResponse`.

Comment: Use a temporary file and you can control when this is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `tempfile.TemporaryFile` in a `with` block. That means the temporary file is deleted when your code exits the `with` context. This is exactly what happens when you `return` from the function, and this is why the file is deleted before FastAPI is able to access it. In other words, the behavior is exactly what you've asked for.

One way of working around this is to use a [`StreamingResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse) instead of a `FileResponse`. Maybe something like this:

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

app = FastAPI()

async def temporaryFileGenerator():
    with TemporaryFile() as fd:
        fd.write('This is a test\n'.encode())
        fd.seek(0)

        while True:
            data = fd.read(1024)
            if not data:
                break

            yield data

@app.get('/example1')
async def example1():
    return StreamingResponse(temporaryFileGenerator())
```

Because we're streaming the file, rather than simply returning a filename, the `with` block doesn't exit until we've streamed all the bytes to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation `TemporaryDirectory()` will remove the directory before the context ends.

- [`TemporaryDirectory()` example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#examples)

Considering your workflow, you should use instead, the `mkdtemp()` function, take in mind that you must handle
the remove action. I create an example, feel free to follow

- [`tempfile.mkdtemp()` reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp)

```py
import os
from tempfile import mkdtemp, TemporaryDirectory


def define_temporal_and_ephemeral_dir() -> str:
    with TemporaryDirectory() as tmp:
        return tmp

def define_temporal_dir() -> str:
    tmp = mkdtemp()

    return tmp


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Ephemeral directory logic.
    ephemeral_path = define_temporal_and_ephemeral_dir()

    is_dir_exists = os.path.exists(ephemeral_path)
    print(f'{ephemeral_path} exists: {is_dir_exists}\n')

    assert is_dir_exists == False

    # Non ephemeral directory logic.
    path = define_temporal_dir()

    is_dir_exists = os.path.exists(path)
    print(f'{path} exists: {is_dir_exists}\n')

    assert is_dir_exists == True

    # The user has to be responsible to manually remove the temporal directory created.
    os.rmdir(path)
    is_dir_exists = os.path.exists(path)

    assert is_dir_exists == False

    print('Non ephemeral directory was removed.')
```

**Disclaimer**: I test this on Mac, I hope you do not found problems while test it on your Windows environment.

**Output**:

```bash
/var/folders/dm/z6w7zmj1193gcb_n0v5p04jw0000gn/T/tmp974g8vpb exists: False

/var/folders/dm/z6w7zmj1193gcb_n0v5p04jw0000gn/T/tmpbujzyodz exists: True

Non ephemeral directory was removed.
```